# Excel dropdown list - automatically fill in values based on selection

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create an internal costing spreadsheet for a restaurant. I've reacquainted myself with how to create dropdown lists (used, in this case, for selecting ingredients).

When someone selects e.g. 'carrots' from the dropdown list, I would like other fields to autopopulate with costing data from another spreadsheet. I know how to make the dropdown pull data from the other sheet, but I do not know how to then have fields on the current sheet pull costing data conditionally based on which item in the dropdown is selected.

Please explain the answer like I'm 5; it's been many years since my Excel ninja days.

TIA

Comment: what code are you using?

Comment: I'm just using the internal formatting/data validation to create the dropdowns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Vlookup if you have the data set up in a table already.  All you have to do is set up your validation as in the image below.  Then you can just use vlookup to refer to that number and the table.  Of course you can clean this up with a more efficient use of your named range and the OFFSET function but this in general may solve your problem.

[image: validation image]

[image: vlookup image]

Comment: Awesome! Vlookup is exactly what I needed. My only problem now is making Vlookup look at another spreadsheet entirely. How do I do that?